# Visual studio code: replace char case while typing in snippet

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I'm trying to write code-snippet for Visual Studio Code and TypeScript. So far I managed to mirror typed word like this:

```
import { ${1:Name}Component } from './${1:name}.component';
```

When I type the word in place #1 it is mirrored to place #2 like this:

```
import { MynameComponent } from './Myname.component';
```

Is it possible to change snippet so the place #2 is in lower case like this:

```
import { MynameComponent } from './myname.component';
```

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to transform snippets has been more recently added in vscode v.1.25.  In your case try this snippet:

```
"import components": {
    "prefix": "isml",
    "body": [
      "import { ${1/(.*)/$1Component } from '.\\/${1:/downcase}/}.component'",
    ],
    "description": "small"
  },
```

Trigger the prefix.  Then hit <kbd>tab</kbd> after you enter your component name (Myname in this example) and it will complete the snippet as you wanted.

```
import { MynameComponent } from './myname.component';
```