# VSCode snippet for importing Angular Material Modules

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I would like to create a snippet tom import an angular material module like so

```js
import { MatToolbarModule } from "@angular/material/toolbar";
etc.
```

This is what i have done so far:

```json
"Import Angular Material Modules": {
        "prefix": "ng-mat-import",
        "body": [
            "import { Mat${1}Module } from '@angular/material/${1/(.*)/downcase/$1}'",
        ]
    },
```

I can't find out what is missing and what is going wrong. The VSCode Documentation is so vague.

The result i would like to get is something like what the answers in [Visual studio code: replace char case while typing in snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48487060/visual-studio-code-replace-char-case-while-typing-in-snippet) does

Comment: What do you get when it’s used?

Comment: Sorry, I'll update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a couple of things incomplete in the transform syntax:

`"import { Mat${1}Module } from \"@angular/material/${1/(.*)/${1:/downcase}/}\";",`

I also used `\"` to include double quotes as your desired end result seems to indicate you want instead of single quotes.  If you just want single quotes there is no need to escape those.

`"import { Mat${1}Module } from '@angular/material/${1/(.*)/${1:/downcase}/}';",`